# RxJava2 - observable.subscribe onComplete is Action type

Tags: java, rx-java2

In RxJava2 you can't do something like this

```
    observable.subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println(s);
    }, e -> {
        System.err.println(e);
    }, c -> {
        System.err.println(c);
    });
```

because c-> {} is not `Action` type(obviously)

Instead you're forced to do something like this

```
    Action onComplete = new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("on complete");
        }       
    };
    observable.subscribe(s -> {
        System.out.println(s);
    }, e -> {
        System.err.println(e);
    },onComplete);
```

Any reason why `onComplete` is not made as `Consumer` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that onComplete doesnt emit any data. A Consumer requires a Type. If something is completed, it's completed.

If you have a `Completable` it only calls onComplete() which doesnt have emitted data aswell.

onCompleted really means completed. onNext/onSuccess means it has data emitted with `Consumer<Type>` while onError means it has a `Consumer<Throwable>`.